# Redirection between domains

Tags: apache, redirect

I have two webs on two different domains. One is on *domain.com* and the other web is on *domain.es*.

I am shutting down the web on *domain.es* but first I have to redirect every request to *domain.es* to *domain.com*. This is easy and I had already done it with `RewriteCond` & `RewriteRule`, like this:

***www.domain.es/***  -- redirects to --> ***www.domain.com/***

But I am having a problem now. I also need to redirect one specific page from *domain.es* to *domain.com* like this:

***www.domain.es/a_page/***  -- redirects to --> ***www.domain.com/another_page/***

I am having problems when redirecting with both rules, as when apache detects a request to ***www.domain.es/a_page*** it goes to ***www.domain.com/*** and not to the specific page I need.

I have this in my virtualhost:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.es/a_page/
RewriteRule ^(.*)& http://www.domain.com/another_page/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.es/
RewriteRule ^(.*)& http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]`

I've got the `[L]` flag so apache would [stop processing rules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html), but this is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.es/a_page/
```

The line above is never going to match anything - you're asking if the **host** is equal to `domain.es/a_page/`, which is a host as well as a path. You need to test against only the hostname, and then redirect based on the path, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.es
RewriteRule ^a_page/ http://www.domain.com/another_page/ [R=301,L]
```